# does "have a go on them" mean "try them" in the following sentence?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

Ok, see this sentence

> He travels to holiday resorts which have water-slides, **has a go on them**
>   and reports back to the travel company where he works.

I would say the phrase "**has a go on them**" in that sentence could have literal meaning "**slide down on water-slides**" or a figurative meaning "**try them**"

does "**have a go on them**" mean "**try them**" in that sentence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To *have a go* means "to try something" in order to experience it.

We can *have a go* **at** some activity.

> Would you like to have a go at this new video game?
>
> The doctor in training had a go at suturing a surgical incision.

But since here the activity involves riding a slide, the preposition chosen by the speaker is **on**.

> Would you like to have a go on the new horse? It's not quite tame yet.